# HTML How to rename multiple Audio Controls created at runtime?

Tags: javascript, audio, vbscript

I have a database that contains the audio titles of multiple records (10 at most).  I loop through the records and create a new audio control for each record.  The only problem is that they are all being named the same so only the first one will play.  I know I have to change the ID's, but I cannot figure out a way to do it. Thank-you in advance for any and all help.

VBscript:

```
do until RS.eof
    R "<td width=12 class=allprint><audio id='yourAudio' preload='none' ><source src='/WaveFiles/" & RS.Fields("AudioIssues") &"' type='audio/wav' /></audio><a href='#' id='audioControl'>Play</a></td>" 
    RS.movenext
 loop
```

Javascript:

```
var yourAudio = document.getElementById('yourAudio'),
    ctrl = document.getElementById('audioControl');
    ctrl.onclick = function () 
    {
        // Update the Button
        var pause = ctrl.innerHTML === 'Pause';
        ctrl.innerHTML = pause ? 'Play' : 'Pause';

        // Update the Audio
        var method = pause ? 'pause' : 'play';
        yourAudio[method]();

        // Prevent Default Action
        return false;
    };
```

Comment: I have resolved this issue.

Comment: Could you please answer your own question, for the benefit of everyone else?